# Single Sign on at Windows 2012 R2 RDS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rds

I setup RDS on 2012 R2 and have a question. 
If I (over the internet, so external network) connect to https://gateway.example.org/RDWeb I can login (with an domain user), I can see a desktop icon. After I clicked on it, the browser downloads a rdp file, after executing it, it ask me again windows credential. 
Of course after I entered it, I am connected to the server.  

 
How can I prevent the second time authentication? Is it possible in general?

Answer (score 1):

You need to deploy RD Gateway

> When you add the Remote Desktop Gateway (RD Gateway) role service to your deployment, it is configured to support web SSO by default.

Reference:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2012/06/25/remote-desktop-web-access-single-sign-on-now-easier-to-enable-in-windows-server-2012/

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for the same information you are asking for and found this guide.

http://woshub.com/sso-single-sign-on-authentication-on-rds/

It still prompts me some times but most of the times i dont get any second prompt.

Comment: Why downvote my answer without writing why?